# Current in RC Step Response circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, step-response

I was simulating the following RC circuit to know the behavior of current through various components.

[image]

I got the following plots..

[image]

To satisfy the KVL at t=0+ voltage across capacitors will indeed change to 1V and because of that there will be impulse current t=0+. But from the plot I can see that there is impulse at t=0+ but also current starts at 0.5mA for C11, -0.5mA for C12 and -1mA for R10.

I am not able to understand  how current is the getting distributed in RC components after impulse current(t>0+).

Please give intuitive explanation for this.

Edit- There is a one mistake in the plot -I(R10) points in clockwise direction.
So the direction is as follows....
I(C11)--Clockwise
-I(C12)--Clockwise
-I(R10)--Clockwise

Comment: Which current directions have you defined as positive for R10 and C12? The graph for I(c12) has a '-' sign in the title.

Comment: Try it with one cap as the load and what do you get?

Comment: Current direction is clock wise...-I(C12) directs in clockwise

Answer (score 1):

> I am not able to understand how current is the getting distributed in RC components after impulse current(t>0+).

Your circuit is non-physical --- you can't have an ideal voltage source applying a step voltage change across a combination of ideal capacitors and get a physically meaningful answer.

In the real world, the behavior would be determined by the internal resistance of the voltage source and the resistance and inductance of the wires connecting the circuit elements. If you want a physically meaningful simulation result, you should include these elements in the circuit model.

In this case, the behavior is determined by the very short but non-zero ramp time you specified for the voltage pulse. If you want to understand what's going on, zoom your plot in on the time between 2.999 and 3.002 us or so. You'll see the capacitors responding exactly as they should to a very quick ramp in applied voltage. To make things more clear, increase the pulse ramp time to 10 or 100 ns instead of 1 ns.

Here I've increased the pulse ramp time to 100 ns and defined all currents to be in the clockwise direction around the main loop and re-done your simulation:

[image]

You can see the capacitors charge nearly equally, as they must to satisfy KCL.

Comment: I understood why capacitor charges  charge nearly equally but I am not getting the behavior of current for t>0

Comment: After charging up, both capacitors have about +1 V  (still taking positive current in the clockwise direction and passive current convention). When t -> infinity we're going to end up with C11 having 2 V and C12 having 0 V. So C11 has to charge up and C12 has to charge down.